# Asana: Query for all tasks in a workspace

Tags: asana, asana-api

I am using **Asana REST API** for connecting Asana tasks with our app. I would need to query for a task from our app, but I don't know in which project to search for that task. Is there a way to query for all tasks in a specific workspace?

As I can see from the documentation it is only possible to search in a specific project:
https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need users to search for a task by name in your app, you should use [Asana's typeahead search API](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/typeaheads).  It provides search for objects from a single workspace. This endpoint should be used to query for objects when creating an auto-completion search feature. This API is meant to provide results quickly and should not be relied upon for accurate or exhaustive search results.

There is no single query to return all tasks in a workspace.  As workplaces have many thousands of tasks, this query would be too broad (and too expensive).

Comment: I need to query over tasks to let user connect existing tasks with my app. I would do that with an input, where user would insert a part of a task name and with a query to asana I would give him autocomplete suggestions. I know that returning all tasks would be expensive but there is paging to solve that problem.

Comment: I can see you are a part of Asana team. Are you guys planning to add this kind of querying in the near future maybe? For now users of my app need to input asana task id to connect existing tasks and that is really not user friendly.

Comment: If you need users to search for a task by name in your app, you should use [Asana's typeahead](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/typeaheads).

Comment: Great that's exactly what I need. Can you please update your answer for other users to find it usefull. When you do I'll accept it. Thank you.